# Silkscreen labels for components - what could Y?? be?

Tags: pcb-design, components, schematics, silkscreen

Components on PCBs are usually labelled using silkscreen markings and most of the markings seem to be quite intuitive:

- **C??** - capacitor
- **D??** - diode
- **FB??** - ferrite bead
- **J??** - jumper wire
- **L??** - inductor
- **LED??** - light emitting diode
- **Q??** - transistor
- **R??** - resistor
- **RJ??** - RJxx connectors
- **SW??** - switch
- **T??** - magnetics (ex. for RJ45 connectors)
- **TP??** - testpoint
- **U??** - packaged integrated circuit

What could be the component marked as '**Y??**' be? Unfortunately the board where I have this marking does not have this place populated.

**[Edit]** Wikipedia has a page about [reference designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol#Reference_designations

Comment: @starblue, I guess we have a winner \o/

Comment: What is it connected to ?

Comment: `J` is also used for connectors.

Comment: @stevenvh yes I thought it was J for Jack and P for plug. Updated: nice link from @starblue.

Comment: Hate to grave dig, but the top comment @starblue link suffered some link rot. Here's a link back to the info it should be referring too: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Electronic_symbol&oldid=412137621

Comment: I’m trying to find out what SA is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Y?? or X?? could both be a crystal or oscillator.  Unfortunately there is no standard for this type of thing.  If you posted a picture of the footprint we could take a better guess.

Also:  Q=Transistor.  RN=Resistor Network.

Comment: Footprint is 2 + 2 pins (square), so it cannot be crystal. Thanks for improving my list :)

Comment: @plaes, not necessarily.  Some crystals packages have 4 leads, even though crystals are only two-terminal devices.  Square would be a bit unusual though.  Still, I agree with David in that it's most likely a crystal.  To really know, you'd have to check the BOM (Bill of Materials).

Comment: @Olin, getting access to BOM is a bit hard, because the PCB is from TP-Link router ;)

Comment: It could be a crystal oscillator module such as one of [these Euroquartz modules](http://www.euroquartz.co.uk/Default.aspx?tabid=121&CategoryID=331&Level=1&SortField=ProductNumber,ProductName&List=1).

Comment: A great many SMD crystals are 4-pin devices! Digikey reports about 3000 in stock, and they're standard on everything we build at work.  The oblong tin can with two through-hole connections is not the only type of crystal.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen Y used to label crystals and oscillators. This is how OrCAD labeled their library parts.